# How to fix error with mutate when trying to create single matrix from multiple datasets

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am trying to take multiple datasets (each dataset = 1 patient) that includes gene and expression data and make a singular matrix, with genes as column name and each row the expression data for the respective patient. The problem is that some patients have genes noted that others do not, so there is not a reference.

Ideally I would like the output below.

```
Dataset 1                   Dataset 2
Gene     expression         Gene     expression
a        0.3                a        0.1
b        0.1                c        -0.3
e        0.2                d        0.05
f        0.2                f        -0.1


Ideal Output:

     a     b     c     d     e     f
1    0.3   0.1   NA    NA    0.2   0.2
2    0.1   NA    -0.3  0.05  NA    -0.1
```

Another user (@mikebader) helped create a possible solution:

```
file_names <- list.files(data_dir)

###Making dataframe list
dflist <- list()

for (i in file_names){
  dflist <- append(dflist, read.csv(i, sep="\t"))
}

###Creating merged DF
df <- bind_rows(
  lapply(seq_along(dflist), function(x) mutate(dflist[[x]], dataset = x))
) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "dataset", names_from = Gene, values_from = expression)
```

However, when I try to execute this I get the following error.

```
 Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I am not sure what the next step I should take is?

Comment: Try changing `lapply(seq_along(dflist), function(x) mutate(dflist[[x]], dataset = x))` to `lapply(seq_along(dflist), function(x) mutate(dflist[x], dataset = x))`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dataframes in a list, bind them together with a unique `id` column and use `pivot_wider` to get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dflist <- list(df1, df2)

bind_rows(dflist, .id = 'id') %>%
  arrange(Gene) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gene, values_from = expression)

#  id       a     b     c     d     e     f
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1       0.3   0.1  NA   NA      0.2   0.2
#2 2       0.1  NA    -0.3  0.05  NA    -0.1
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gene = c("a", "b", "e", "f"), expression = c(0.3, 
0.1, 0.2, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Gene = c("a", "c", "d", "f"), expression = c(0.1, 
-0.3, 0.05, -0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It was because I was not correctly making a list of dataframes. Instead I used the below, and then the code worked.

```
dflist <- lapply(file_names, read.csv, sep="\t")
```